# Modeling one-to-many relationship when the many-side can be either too small or too big in number

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need some advice.

I am trying to model a Text to Speech solution. Blog owners can integrate our widget into their sites and their visitors can listen to the article.

A single publisher can have multiple integrations(based on the fact that they might have multiple sites or multiple sub-sites).

The number of articles in integration can be too small or too big based on how big the publisher is. Articles will be accessed less frequently or too frequently based on the number of daily visitors on the site.

So the User has many Integrations. There are many Articles in an Integration.
[image]

The data access pattern looks like below:

```
getIntegrationByUserId(userId)
getIntgrationById(integrationId)
getContentByIntegrationId(integrationId)
getContentByIntegrationIdBetweenDates(integrationId, from_date, to_date)
getContentByIntegrationIdAndContentId(integrationId, contentId)
```

Following is the entity chart which I am planning.

[image]

For the Date Filter I am thinking to add the following GSI:

```
GSI1PK: CONTENTS#<TimeStamp>
GSI1SK: CONTENT#<ContentId>
```

The following are my questions:

1. How to support getContentByIntegrationIdBetweenDates(integrationId, from_date, to_date) in the above model.
2. Should I make Integration or User as Primary Key? I am worried about the distribution of the content evenly among the partitions. Some users or integration will have a comparatively high number of content and frequent access to the content. Will the above model result in a hotkey scenario?

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the model like this:

```
User 
-----------
user_id: pk; uuid
... user specific attributes ...

Integration
-----------
integration_id: pk, uuid
user_id: uuid, references User:user_id

Content
-----------
content_id: pk, uuid
content: text
created_at: date
integration_id: uuid, references Integration:integration_id

GSI: 
Integration: on user_id
Content: on integration_id, with created_at as sort key
```

> How to support getContentByIntegrationIdBetweenDates(integrationId,
> from_date, to_date) in the above model.

By using the integration_id with created_at GSI on the Content table. Apply date filtering.

> Should I make Integration or User as Primary Key? I am worried about
> the distribution of the content evenly among the partitions. Some
> users or integration will have a comparatively high number of content
> and frequent access to the content. Will the above model result in a
> hotkey scenario?

The only concern I see using this model is the integration_id GSI on the `Content` table. If there is too much content per integration (per user is safe), it can lead to problems. Dynamodb has a 10GB limit per partition, but in case your key exceeds that, it will transparently create a new one, so it won't fail. Sort key is needed for that split, so `created_at` comes in handy for that also.

Comment: Having separate tables makes more sense or having a single table? In a lot of places, they have suggested going for a single table.

Comment: In NoSql your model is created based on the queries you will do on it.  So it depends a lot I would say. You can for example embed User in Integration. But if you change for example the first name, you need to do that manually for all Integration objects. So depends a lot on your queries and updates